# saving base64 data - row size too large issue

Tags: mysql, longtext

I have 22 database fields of type `longtext`. If I try saving 12 of the fields with the following data I get the following error:

```
#1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not     
counting BLOBs, is 8126. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

It saves fine if I only save 11 fields. Here's the data:

```
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
```

How can I fix the issue? How can I increase the bytes of the row size so it is more than 8126?

Comment: "Row size too large." - that sounds quite conclusive.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me if you have a question.  But the data shown is 684 bytes.  684*12=8208 (>8126). So, as Mitch points out, it is fairly clear why the error occurs.

Comment: @MarkWilkins Thanks for the response. My question is, how can I fix the issue? How can I increase the bytes of the row size so it is more than 8126?

Comment: @MitchWheat Sorry, I've updated my question so it's more clear.

Comment: @ImranAzad 11 fields of type `LONGTEXT` are you _sure_ they should be in the same table? What's the use case for this?

Comment: @Shef Thanks for the response. The table contains patient information that needs to be encrypted.

Comment: @ImranAzad Can't you split the table up? This will be hunting you always.

Comment: @Shef I hadn't thought of that. It's a good idea! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the row size limit for InnoDB tables, in this links you can find some approaches to solve this:

- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/04/07/innodb-row-size-limitation/
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/innodb-create-table-error-row-size-too-large

Answer (score 1):

Columns of type Varchar's, text, and blob arent included in the innodb row size limit.. so if you have a lot of columns that aren't you can get that error.

I had a load of char(1)'s that I changed to varchar and it fixed the problem nicely