# MySQL Row size too large

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to insert data into a MySQL table that is using the innodb storage engine and am getting this error:

> Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

I understand the error, but my table is made up of almost only text and mediumtext columns.
Basically, I am trying to store a bunch of XML responses from a web service that are of variable length. I am able to save these responses (the requests happen sequentially in a batch process) until I get to col14, where the insert of the response gives the above error

My backup idea if I can't get this to work is to just save the XML on the server and put the file location in the database.

I have included the create table code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qb_results` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col3` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col4` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col5` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col6` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col7` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col8` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col9` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col10` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col11` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col12` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col13` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col14` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col15` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col16` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col17` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `col18` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `updated_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=61 ;
```

I changed columns to be numbered because they were business specific and didn't feel it was necessary or relevant to include their actual column names. Normalizing would actually solve the problem but still does not explain the error given the context (error says to use text columns, which are being used already)

Comment: Numbered columns... smells like a candidate for normalization? That would also solve the length problem. Note that using utf-8 drastically increases used space in the non-text columns.

Comment: Numbered columns? Just... don't. Make it qb_results (id, set, data), so that you'll have records instead of columns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [saving base64 data - row size too large issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220489/saving-base64-data-row-size-too-large-issue)

Answer (score -2):

I was also having the same issue. Do the following:
set ENGINE=MyISAM.
Also, if your script is bulky you might want to change the execution time of your script.
In that case open the configuration file of PHP (php.ini for windows) and set

```
max_execution_time=150 //(suppose) you can set it whatever you feel right.
```