# Update row in mysql table - Row size is too large

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying to update a row in a table but it comes back with:

`Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs`

All of my fields apart from the ID are BLOBs so I have no idea what the error is meaning.

Can anybody help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220489/saving-base64-data-row-size-too-large-issue

Comment: This smells like a poor design. What type of data are you storing in these rows?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your columns type to TEXT as mysql said.

Comment: There are about 40 column in the table